# Getting error when sending POST request to server using MQL4

Tags: mql4

I am trying to post data using an MQL4 script to a local server on the same network and I am getting errors.

Here is the code:

```
#import  "Wininet.dll"
int InternetOpenW(string, int, string, string, int);
int InternetConnectW(int, string, int, string, string, int, int, int); 
int InternetOpenUrlW(int, string, string, int, int, int);
int InternetReadFile(int, string, int, int& OneInt[]);
int InternetCloseHandle(int); 
int HttpOpenRequestW(int, string, string, string, string, string& AcceptTypes[], int, int);
bool HttpSendRequestW(int, string, int, string, int);
#import

#import "kernel32.dll"
int GetLastError(void);
#import
int OnInit()
{
    string headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string data = "test=test";
    string acceptTypes[1] = {"*/*"};

    int HttpOpen = InternetOpenW("HTTP_Client_Sample", 1, "", "", 0);  
    int HttpConnect = InternetConnectW(HttpOpen, 
    "http://192.168.0.201/api", 7777, "", "", 3, 0, 1);
    int HttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(HttpConnect, "POST", "/index.php", "HTTP/1.1", "", 
    acceptTypes, 0, 1);        
  
    bool result = HttpSendRequestW(HttpRequest, headers, StringLen(headers), data, 
    StringLen(data));
    Alert ("Last MSDN Error =: ", kernel32::GetLastError());

    int read[1]; // not used
    Alert("This is the POST result: ", result);
    if (HttpOpen > 0)
        InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpen);
    if (HttpRequest > 0)
        InternetCloseHandle(HttpRequest);

    Alert("DONE");
}
```

So the MSDN error is 6. Tried to look that up, but came up with nothing.
The result is false, so obviously not working.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Why not use the inbuilt and supported means of achieving POST requests? [WebRequest()](https://docs.mql4.com/common/webrequest)